# How to insert Point to mysql using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, point

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.8.Final and I want to insert a "Point" to mysql but show this error Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable  {
    @Column(name = "location")
    private Point location;
}
```

Comment: Please give more details. If Address and Point are annotated with @Entity this should work.

Comment: Please post the error logs.